Show that in an equilateral triangle of side 1, among the 10 points inside it there are 2 points whose distance is $\leq \frac{1}{3}$
This should be shown by the pigeonhole principle. In the 10 points, the 3 vertices are included. I guess I need to split the triangle in some way. I tried dividing the triangle in several ways, but I couldn't see how any of them helped me use the pigeonhole principle. As an example, one way would be to draw the medians from all the vertices which would produce 6 equal regions, but that's as far as I get

By dividing each side of triangle into three equal line segments, we can get $9$ equilateral triangles having side of length $\frac{1}{3}$. then put a point in each triangle and when you put the last point in anywhere of the largest triangle we will get the distance between last point and and a point of previous points $\leq \frac{1}{3}$

